# Django button in Modelclass

Tags: python, django

I'm making an inventory app in which I could update the values of the products from my 'home.html'.

My proj name is Inventory
App name is myapp

Problem I am facing is that every time I update the value of a Stock from my homepage, it adds a new Product instead of updating the one that I want!
I am using the ModelsForm Class provided by Django.
Using Django=1.11 and Python=3.6

My project's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.views import home



urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
url(r'^myapp/home/', home, name='home'),
]
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Inventory


class Operations(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Inventory
    fields = ('stocks_left',)
```

My app's Model.py:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Inventory(models.Model):
"""
Model representing a the inventory.
"""
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
inventory_name = models.CharField("INVENTORY NAME" ,max_length=200,   help_text="This contains the Inventory name:")
short_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="This contains an abbreviation:")
inventory_code = models.IntegerField("INVENTORY CODE" ,default = '0', help_text="This contains the Inventory code:")
price = models.IntegerField(default = '0')
stocks_left = models.IntegerField("STOCKS LEFT",default = '0')
def __str__(self):
    """
    String for representing the Model object (in Admin site etc.)
    """
    return '{0} ({1}) ({2})'.format(self.inventory_name,self.inventory_code,self.stocks_left)
```

My app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login


app_name= 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', login, {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),
]
```

and my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views import generic
from django.http import HttpResponse
from myapp.models import Inventory
from .forms import Operations

def home(request):
names = Inventory.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = Operations(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        stocks_left = form.save(commit=False)
        stocks_left.save()
        return redirect('myapp/home.html')
else:
    form = Operations()
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html', { "names": names, "form": form})
```

and my home.html template:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Inventory</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <table border="5" cellpadding="10" width="1000">
        <thead align="center">
        <tr>
          <th align="center">#</th>
          <th align="center">Name</th>
          <th align="center">Inventory Code</th>
          <th align="center">Stocks left</th>
          <th align="center">Operations</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          {% for x in names %}
          <td align="center"> {{ x }}</td>
          <td align="center"> {{ x.inventory_name }}</td>
          <td align="center"> {{ x.inventory_code }}</td>
          <td align="center"> {{ x.stocks_left }}</td>
          <td><form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}{{form}}<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></form><br></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The way your code is designed should indeed create a new object. If you want to update your stock, a simple solution is to create a new page with [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). If you prefer to keep everything one the same page, you should use a custom form and pass the object ID and the stock.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do,

Create 2 fields in forms,

```
class Operations(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ('stocks_left','inventory_name')
```

When you get the data in the view,

```
if request.method == "POST":
  form = Operations(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    inv_obj = form.cleaned_data.get('inventory_name') 
    inv_model_obj = Inventory.objects.get(inventory_name=inv_obj) #make sure to declare in the models that this inventory_name is unique
    inv_model_obj.stocks_left = form.cleaned_data.get('stocks_left')
    inv_model_obj.save()
    return redirect('myapp/home.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not pass `instance=the_instance_you_want_to_edit` to a ModelForm it will create a new instance. How else would the ModelForm know what model instance you mean to edit?

BaseModelForm.**init**

```
    if instance is None:
        # if we didn't get an instance, instantiate a new one
        self.instance = opts.model()
        object_data = {}
    else:
        self.instance = instance
        object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
```

Anyway, it is not really going to work well if you want to keep it all on one page. Either you manually type in the object_id to pass to the ModelForm later. Or you create a FormSet with each Form representing an Inventory object plus an input field for 'stocks_left'.

The former is a bit iffy because if you mistype the primary key you are going to change the stock of the wrong Inventory without noticing (or throw a DoesNotExist error down the road).
And the latter is total overkill if you only want to change a single Inventory.

You have two options and either option requires another page/template. 
One page displays your overview and the other serves to update an Inventory's stock. The overview contains links to the individual update pages.

---

Capture the primary key of the object you want to edit from the url.

```
url(r'^myapp/home/([0-9]+)/$)', home, name='home-update')
```

The URL dispatcher will then call your `home` view function with the request and the captured parameter and you can instantiate the ModelForm with it.

```
def home(request, pk):
    names = Inventory.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Operations(request.POST, instance=Inventory.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('myapp/home.html')
    else:
        form = Operations()
        return render(request, 'myapp/a_very_basic_template_to_display_a_form.html', {"form": form})
```

---

Or use a class based UpdateView (for your 'update' page):

```
class InventoryStockUpdateView(views.generic.UpdateView):
    model = Inventory
    template_name = 'myapp/a_very_basic_template_to_display_a_form.html'

    fields = ['stocks_left']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

With this in urls.py:

```
url(r'^myapp/home/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$)', InventoryStockUpdateView.as_view(), name='home-update')
```

To edit Inventory with the primary key 31415 you would then type '...home/31415' into your browser.

---

UPDATE:
Have you had a look at django's admin actions? They let you edit instances from the changelist by selecting them via a checkbox and then running an admin action on them. While that may not be quite what you want, investigating how exactly they work should teach you some tricks that would help you in your current task.

To maybe give you a few pointers on how to proceed: add `<a>` tags to your template, two (+/-) for every 'row' of instances you are displaying.
The href attribute of each tag of a should contain the row's instance and the element's 'job' (adding or subtracting a stock). These two values will be used in the url conf much like I described above...
As to how you properly build the href attribute; the [template tag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) should help.
Maybe like so:

```
    <tr>
      {% for x in names %}
      <td align="center"> {{ x }}</td>
      <td align="center"> {{ x.inventory_name }}</td>
      <td align="center"> {{ x.inventory_code }}</td>
      <td align="center"> {{ x.stocks_left }}</td>
      <td><a href={% url ??? %}>click me to subtract!</a></td>
      <td><a href={% url ??? %}>click me to add!</a></td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Of course, you would also need a new view function to handle those urls, but those shouldn't be very difficult to figure out.

Comment: I understand but My main idea was to create a login based app where after logging in you get few details about the things you have in stock and you get + & - Buttons in front of those things so that from there only you can edit  just the stock_left instead of logging in to the admin and changing the model from there. I'm new to Django so I was just trying out how to use forms although, do you think you could help me out with my initial problem statement of creating those buttons?

Comment: Do you want to:  +/- edit ... a) a _single_ stock by _one_ at a time? b) _several_ stocks by _one_ at a time? c) a single stock by a _variable_ amount at a time? or d)  several stocks by a _variable_ amount at a time?

Comment: A single stock by one at a time